# Not receiving verification code via text when signing up

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I am currently building a React-Native mobile application. I'm also using AWS Amplify on the backend. When the user is signing up, they are supposed to receive a SMS verification code to verify their account and allow them to sign up but I'm not receiving the verification code. I'm not not getting an Alerts to say that any issues are occurring and in the console.log it says the message is being sent. On AWS Amplify, I have MFA enabled and the sign up verification is set to SMS. Even though the verification code isn't being sent, the details are added to Amplify but is unverified. I have included the code for the sign up page, the page where the user is supposed to enter the verification code, aws-exports.js and the console log when the sign up button is pressed showing the verification code has been sent. Something to also bear in mind is the attribute NICKNAME is just to hold some other personal information e.g. IBAN.

SignUpPage.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useState} from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TextInput, Alert } from "react-native";
import CustomButton from "../../components/CustomButton/CustomButton";
import { ScrollView } from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
const SignUpScreen = () => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
    const [secondName, setSecondName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [phoneNum, setPhoneNum] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [iban, setiban] = useState('')
    const navi = useNavigation()

    const onRegisterBusinessPressed = async () => {
        try {
            const response= await Auth.signUp({
                username: email,
                password,
                attributes: {
                    email,
                    name: firstName,
                    family_name: secondName,
                    phone_number: phoneNum,
                    nickname: iban
                }
            });
            console.log(response);
            navi.navigate('ConfirmSignUp')
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert('Oops', error.message);
        }
    }

    const onSignInPressed = () => {
        console.warn("Return to Sign in pressed")
        navi.navigate('SignIn')
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <View style={styles.root}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Register</Text>
                <TextInput style={styles.container} placeholder="First name" value={firstName} onChangeText={setFirstName} />
                <TextInput style={styles.container} placeholder="Second name" value={secondName} onChangeText={setSecondName} />
                <TextInput style={styles.container} placeholder="Email address" value={email} onChangeText={setEmail} />
                <TextInput style={styles.container} placeholder="Phone number" value={phoneNum} onChangeText={setPhoneNum} />
                <TextInput style={styles.container} placeholder="Password" value={password} onChangeText={setPassword} secureTextEntry={true} />
                <TextInput style={styles.container} placeholder="IBAN" value={iban} onChangeText={setiban} />
                <CustomButton text="Register account" onPress={onRegisterBusinessPressed} />
                <CustomButton text="Have an account? Sign in" onPress={onSignInPressed} type="TERTIARY" />
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    root: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 25
    },

    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        margin: 10
    },
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: '100%',
        borderColor: '#E8E8E8',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        marginVertical: 7
    }

});

export default SignUpScreen
```

ConfirmSignUp.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from "react";
import CustomButton from "../../components/CustomButton/CustomButton";
import { useNavigation, useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

const ConfirmSignUp = () =>{
    const [smsCode, setSmsCode] = useState('');
    const navi = useNavigation()
  
const onConfirmPressed = async() =>{
    try {
        const response = await Auth.confirmSignUpSignUp(email, smsCode)
        console.log(response)
    } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert("Oops ", error.message)
    }
    console.warn("Confirm Pressed")
    navi.navigate('SignIn')
}
const onResendPressed = () =>{
    console.warn("Resend Pressed")
}

return(
    <View style={styles.root}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Confirm your phone number</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.container} placeholder="Enter SMS code" value={smsCode} onChangeText={setSmsCode}/>
        <CustomButton text="Verify code" onPress={onConfirmPressed}/>
        <CustomButton text="Resend code" onPress={onResendPressed} type="TERTIARY"/>
    </View>
)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    root:{
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 25
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        margin: 10
    },
    container: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: '100%',
        borderColor: '#E8E8E8',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        marginVertical: 7
    }

});

export default ConfirmSignUp
```

aws-exports.js

```
/* eslint-disable */
// WARNING: DO NOT EDIT. This file is automatically generated by AWS Amplify. It will be overwritten.

const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "eu-north-1",
    "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "eu-north-1:bb6d70b5-4ac7-454a-98b6-f827b918b981",
    "aws_cognito_region": "eu-north-1",
    "aws_user_pools_id": "eu-north-1_wyBcB9eln",
    "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "7hup6euba4kk9fdu7q0q10vqq1",
    "oauth": {},
    "aws_cognito_username_attributes": [
        "EMAIL"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_social_providers": [],
    "aws_cognito_signup_attributes": [
        "NAME",
        "FAMILY_NAME",
        "EMAIL",
        "PHONE_NUMBER",
        "NICKNAME"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_mfa_configuration": "ON",
    "aws_cognito_mfa_types": [
        "SMS"
    ],
    "aws_cognito_password_protection_settings": {
        "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
        "passwordPolicyCharacters": []
    },
    "aws_cognito_verification_mechanisms": [
        "PHONE_NUMBER"
    ]
};


export default awsmobile;
```

[image: log after sign up is pressed]

[image: Sign up page]

[image]

Comment: Are you calling Amplify.configure(awsmobile) so the AWS library knows your config?

Comment: @Penquin in app.js? import config from './src/aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(config) is this what you mean?

Comment: Anything in cloudwatch?

Comment: @Luke Im looking at the logs and is saying success in the response body with 200 status code.

Comment: @AdamDalton yes, I suspect you need to pass the amplify configuration before you can do anything useful.